# Vue.js return and render templates

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have 2 templates in which the child one loop through images.I need to send it to the parent as array of templates and then loop them in the parent in order to avoid duplicates.How to accomplish that? below are the codes :

Products.vue (parent):

```
<template>
<div>
              <div class="u-repeater u-repeater-1"><!--product_item-->
                <div
                    class="u-align-center-lg u-align-center-sm u-align-center-xl u-align-center-xs u-container-style u-products-item u-repeater-item">
                  <ImageComponent></ImageComponent>
                </div><!--/product_item--><!--product_item-->
</div>
</div>
</template>
```

ImageComponent.vue: (child)

```
<template>
  <div class="u-container-layout u-similar-container u-container-layout-1">
    <div v-for="n in Object.keys(products[0]).length" :key="n">
      <img alt="" :src="products[n].image" data-image-width="510" data-image-height="340"
           class="u-expanded-width-lg u-expanded-width-md u-expanded-width-sm u-expanded-width-xl u-image u-image-default u-product-control u-image-1">
      <div
          class="u-align-center u-container-style u-expanded-width-xs u-group u-opacity u-opacity-70 u-palette-5-light-2 u-group-1">
        <div class="u-container-layout u-container-layout-2">
          <h4 data-animation-name="fadeIn" data-animation-duration="1000" data-animation-delay="0"
              data-animation-direction="Up" class="u-product-control u-text u-text-1 animated fadeInUp-played"
              style="will-change: transform, opacity; animation-duration: 1000ms;">
            <a href="#" class="u-product-title-link"> {{ products[n].model }} </a>
          </h4>
          <div class="u-align-left u-product-control u-product-price u-product-price-1">
            <div class="u-price-wrapper u-spacing-10">
              <div class="u-hide-price u-old-price">$12</div>
              <div class="u-price" style="font-size: 1.25rem; font-weight: 700;">{{ products[n].price }}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a href="#"
             class="u-align-center-xs u-border-active-none u-border-hover-none u-btn u-btn-rectangle u-button-style u-none u-product-control u-text-palette-1-base u-btn-1">Add
            to Cart</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {mapState} from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "ImageComponent",
data(){
    return{
      items:[

      ]
    }
},

  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      products: (state) => state.products,

    }),
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.u-palette-5-light-2, .u-body.u-palette-5-light-2, .u-container-style.u-palette-5-light-2:before, .u-container-layout.u-palette-5-light-2:before, .u-table-alt-palette-5-light-2 tr:nth-child(even) {
  color: #111111;
  background-color: unset;
}
</style>
```

Remark: not all codes are written, just to give the main idea.
Thanks for help.

Comment: `I need to send it to the parent as array of templates` What do you mean by this?

Comment: Your data is in a vuex store. You can access the product data as single source of truth from your store. So can't you just import the store in your parent and manipulate it there?

Comment: Hi  bassxzero, I mean I need the parent get all the child templates to avoid duplicates of code.

Comment: Probably I could but then the parent get too much crowded, I am trying to avoid that through returning one single child template that have all the image loops .